# ruby motion KeychainItemWrapper set extra attribute

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, keychainitemwrapper

I have existing KSecValueData and KSecAttrAccount

but when I tried to define a new 1

```
self.username = @keychain.objectForKey kSecAttrLabel
```

it give me undefine local variable, I checked out the documentation ,i thought kSecAttrLabel was initialise as default, so that we can use it anytime/? what other can be use??

Thanks...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

Comment: It will be great if you provide the documentation link in your post too.

Comment: what kind of documentation?

Comment: you wrote that *I checked out the documentation*,I am asking for to give that link too..

Comment: I added the documentation...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When rubymotion imports constants/globals such as `kSecAttrLabel` then it capitalizes the leading 'k', so in this case you would use `KSecAttrLabel`.

This is because ruby constants should start with an uppercase letter.